# Need help in F# sequence

Tags: f#

I am new to F# (started to learn only today), I tried to implement fibonacci sequence recursively. I am not sure whether it is syntactically or logically wrong

```
let rec fibonacciRecursive (x : int) = seq{
        match x with
        | 0     -> yield! [0]
        | 1     -> yield! [0; 1]
        | _     -> yield! fibonacciRecursive 
                   |> Seq.pairwise 
                   |> Seq.map (fun (prev, next) -> prev + next)
                   |> Seq.toList
        }
```

Comment: On the third line under `match`, you're calling `fibonacciRecursive` without a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're trying to create the Fibonacci sequence would work better using the handy [`Seq.unfold`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.unfold%5B'state,'t%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) function, which was designed for this sort of situation. You pass it a function and an initial state, and it calls that function repeatedly to calculate the next value of the sequence based on the current state. Its parameters are given in the order `Seq.unfold function initialState`, but I usually prefer to write it as `initialState |> Seq.unfold function`. The function returns either `None` to stop the sequence, or `Some (nextValue, nextState)` to continue the sequence (which can create infinite sequences).

In the case of the Fibonacci sequence, creating it with `Seq.unfold` would look like this:

```
let fibUnfold = (0,1) |> Seq.unfold (fun (a, b) -> Some(b+a, (b, b+a)))
let fib = seq { yield 0; yield 1; yield! fibUnfold }

for i in fib |> Seq.take 10 do  // Infinite sequence, so take a finite number
    printf "%d, "
printfn ""
// Prints "0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, "
```

Answer (score 1):

The recipe for creating a sequence recursively is to create a function that creates the sequence from some "state" on (here `continueFrom` state being `a` and `b`). The function should yield an item and then yield itself with state corresponding the sequence from next item on.

```
 let fibonacciSequence =
     let rec continueFrom a b =
         seq {
             yield a
             yield! continueFrom b (a + b)
         }
     continueFrom 0 1
```

Note that `fibonacciSequence` is an infinite sequence which means that you cannot convert it to a list directly. If you want first `n` items you can use `Seq.take n fibonacciSequence`.

Answer (score 0):

As Fyodor pointed out, there is a syntactic error on the third `match` case, because you're not actually passing the parameter to the `fibonacciRecursive` function.  However, if you fix this by passing `x`, you'll then find that your function throws a `StackOverflowException` when executed.  This is because you're recursively attempting to generate the entire sequence for each value.

A very simple solution for Fibonacci in F# looks like this:

```
let rec fib = function
| 0 -> 0
| 1 -> 1
| n -> fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)
```

However, this will also eventually hit a stack overflow, because the calls are not 'tail recursive', meaning the recursion is not the last thing to happen in the function (in this case, the addition is the last thing to happen).  You can make a tail-recursive solution by deferring the execution of each element with a continuation, so that the recursive call is in tail position:

```
let fib n =
    let rec fib cont = function
    | n when n < 2 -> cont n
    | n -> (n - 1) |> fib (fun x -> (n - 2) |> fib (fun y -> cont (x + y))) 
    fib id n
```

This is a little hard to follow, and it often takes a while to get used to thinking about writing functions this way.  Here's a version using double back-ticks to allow descriptive names for the parameters to the continuations, if that helps to understand what's happening:

```
let fib n =
    let rec fib cont = function
    | n when n < 2 -> 
        cont n
    | n -> 
        (n - 1) |> fib (fun ``fib (n-1)`` -> 
            (n - 2) |> fib (fun ``fib (n-2)`` -> 
                cont (``fib (n-1)`` + ``fib (n-2)``))) 
    fib id n
```

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by others, you have a problem in the recursive call (you forgot the parameters for your call).

As Aaron pointed out in his answer, it is desirable that you end up with a tail recursive version of your implementation to avoid stack overflows.

Here is how I would do it:

Whenever you have some recursive function which is not tail recursive (it ends with `f x (recCall y)`, you create yourself a recursive sub-function which looks like `let rec subF x y`, i.e. you move the tail part of your original code into your helper sub-function `subf`). With fibonacci, here is how it would look in my case:

```
let fib n =
    let rec worker state x =
        if x = 0 then state 
        else
            match state with
            | [] -> worker [0] (x-1)
            | [0] -> worker [1;0] (x-1)
            | (a::b::_) -> worker ((a+b)::state) (x-1)
    worker [] n
```

And - as is easy to see, the recursive call of the sub-function `worker` *is* tail recursive (it does nothing else after the recursive call).